# Do we need to pay royalties to unreal if we use admob in an app developed using unreal engine

Tags: admob, unreal-engine4

I don't have much experience with licensing. In unreal's website it's stated as follows for publishing an app:

**License for Publishing: This license is free to use and incurs 5% royalties when you monetize your game or other interactive off-the-shelf product and your lifetime gross revenues from that product exceed $1,000,000 USD.**

Is using only admob for ads is same as monetizing? Do I have to pay Unreal 5% royalties?
If yes, How I'm supposed to pay them (manually? or it happens automatically).
If what I've understood till now, is absolutely wrong please feel free to correct me. I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section titled *Royalty* in the [EULA](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/eula/publishing).
It clarifies the exact terms and also provides information on how to make the payments.

Ad revenue is still revenue.

> You agree to pay Epic a royalty equal to 5% of all worldwide gross
> revenue actually attributable to each Product, regardless of whether
> that revenue is received by you or any other person or legal entity,
> as follows:

*(omitted for brevity)*

> d. Your revenue from in-app advertising and
> affiliate programs;

But also be sure to read the section titled *"However, no royalty is owed on the following forms of revenue:"*, there are many different exceptions to when royalty is owed.